# unix command in php

Tags: php

convert alpha_extract.png -background Yellow -alpha shape   alpha_shape.png

this is unix command in php how can we run in php

Answer (score 1):

```
system("convert alpha_extract.png -background Yellow -alpha shape alpha_shape.png");
```

Comment: i  run it but not get the result  alpha_shape.png image

Comment: does the php deamon have write permissions in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$cmd_convert = `convert alpha_extract.png -background Yellow -alpha shape alpha_shape.png`;
```

Works with some Commands, hope with convert too :)